# How to use Google as identity provider to authenticate clients at a RESTful web service?

Tags: java, web-services, oauth-2.0, credentials, restful-authentication

I am writing a RESTful web service whose methods must perform their tasks only for authenticated users. Users of the web service must first create an account (sign up/register) on the web service through the Google identity provider before using its methods and they must sign in with Google for accessing the functionalities provided by the web service.

Here's an example scenario: X is a registered user at Google, the web service doesn't know about X and it never heard from him before. X wants to register at the web service, authenticating himself through Google.

So it's like X is saying to the web service "hey, I'm X, Google can prove it that I am X, here is the token that Google provided plus some other information that Google already know about me and I am too lazy to retype (name, surname, email, etc.).

When the web service receives the token and the information from X, how can the web service to be sure that X is really is X? Should it contact Google, passing to it the token received from X?

By following the [Instructions for the OAuth2 V1 Command-Line Sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/oauth2-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) I have managed to have the demo app produce a serialized object, saved in `.store/oauth2_sample/StoredCredential`, and a token containing attributes like access_type, audience, email, expires_in, issued_to, scope, user_id, verified_email.

It is not clear to me what information must the client pass to the service in the registration phase and in the utilization phase, what information should the service store during the registration of user in order to be able to authenticate them later and how to do that.

And where/what is this token? Is it that whole serialized object in `.store/oauth2_sample/StoredCredential` or is it a single attribute of that object?

How can X pass the token to the web service? Does each of the methods exposed by the web service have to have an additional parameter dedicated to receive this authenticating token?